# How to get the selected cell value in GridView in ASP.NET Webforms?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a project showing data once I clicked a cell on GridView except on first column ID.

### ID  | Name | Department | Position

### 1   | John | IT         | IT Support

### 2   | Max  | Finance    | Payroll

3   | Joe  | HR         | Recruiter

Once I click John it shows his full name.
Once I click IT it shows IT Department details.
Once I click IT Support it shows employee details.
So on to last.

Comment: What is your question? What did you do so far? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: I cannot help you because your question is very poor and not related to specific point of help, please take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask